# Find text and add css without using jquery/javascript

Tags: html, css

I have table like this:

Table1:

```
<table> 
 <tr>
  <th>Title1</th>
  <th>Title2</th>
  <th>Title3</th>
  <th>Title4</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Text1</td>
  <td>Text2</td>
  <td>Text3</td>
  <td>Text4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Text1</td>
  <td>Text2</td>
  <td>Text3</td>
  <td>Text4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Table2:

```
<table> 
 <tr>
  <th>Title1</th>
  <th>Title2</th>
  <th>Title4</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Text1</td>
  <td>Text2</td>
  <td>Text4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Text1</td>
  <td>Text2</td>
  <td>Text4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Table3:

```
<table> 
 <tr>
  <th>Title4</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Text4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Text4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here I have 3 tables(3 tables is not constant. But all table have **Title4** heading but different position. I need to change color for all tables for the text "Title4" only without using jquery/javascript. Only using in css. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried some other. [title~=Title4] {     background-color: yellow; } . But I know this is wrong method.

Comment: You can simple refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: Hi @all. Just now I updated more details with my question. sorry for that when i add the question minimum information.

Answer (score 4):

Updated good point from @shaggy:
What you want to do is add a class (classes are used more than once) which is the css selector `.` to each `<th>` element that will contain Title4.

```
<th class="blue">Title4</th>

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpXQOM

Leaving up for reference,
This should work use nth child selector. It takes advantage of being able to select a certain child of an element. It first looks for any `<table>` then the (4) represents the fourth `<th>` in the table here it is title4!

```
 table th:nth-child(4) {
        background: blue;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I have more than 5 tables. So "Title4" is not constant position.(I mean its not 4th th). It will change based on table. so I need to change all tables content "Title4" only need to change the color. I think my question is not clear. I will update

Comment: This will work for multiple tables! see my updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpXQOM

Comment: Sorry for the minimum information my quesiton. I updated the question with more info.

Comment: what you could do here is add an id to each tables title 4 like so http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpXQOM

Comment: IDs should be unique and, as per the question, there are multiple tables here so it would be better to use a class in this instance.

Comment: The table th don't have any class. because the table render from database and its cann't able to add class('blue').

Comment: @RSKMR Are you using PHP to loop and pull each set of data?

Comment: No. render data from Java/GWT.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you are pulling the data I could come up with a Java solution as well, basically when iterating through adding a class to each element and than using css to target these elements for the color change

Comment: Sample Code:               getModelTable().addColumn(new TextCell(), "Bill Amount", new GetValue<String, BillDo>() {
   public String getValue(BillDo bill) {    
    return BQFormatter.formatCurrency(bill.getBillAmount());
   }
  }, null);
  getModelTable().setRightAlignFlag(true);
  getModelTable().addColumn(new TextCell(), "Pay Amount", new GetValue<String, BillDo>() {
   public String getValue(BillDo bill) {
    return BQFormatter.formatCurrency(bill.getPayAmount());
   }
  }, null);